# How to let a VueJS component work only as a wrapper instead of having control of all the html?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In other words one might have an html at some point which looks like this:
`<bloglink blogposturl="http://a.link" blogposttitle="my title" ></bloglink>`

And the template attribute like so:
...
`template: '<h3><i><a style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;" v-on:click="load_blog_page(blogposturl)">{{blogposttitle}}</a></i></h3>',`
...

But what if one wanted to express instead

```
<bloglink blogposturl="http://a.link" blogposttitle="my title" > 
  <p>.....complex html in here.... which is not dynamic....</p>
</bloglink>
```

One would want to keep this html when loading the webpage instead of being completely replaced.

One way would be to take this complex html and insert it as a parameter being careful with escaping properly etc. but this does not seem very elegant.

What is the recommended way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vue [component slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html).

for example:

ParentComponent:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

SomeOtherComponent:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <parent>
            <p>whatever</p>
        </parent>
    </div>
</template>
```